# Significado do % em strings!

Tags: python, formatação

Olá, estava acompanhando uma video aula de formatação de strings em Python e vi que o professor usava  %d e %, mas a minha internet esta com problemas para carregar o video, queria saber o que significa esse %

Comment: Se não me engano, é para formatação. O **%d** é formatado e substituído por algo quando a string é chamada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dito, o % é para formatação.

```
>>> "Uso do percent %d" % 30
```

O primeiro **%d** marca que neste ponto há um lugar (placeholder) para substituir por um decimal (a ser informado futuramente).

O segundo % efetivamente realiza a substituição pelos valores a direita.